# Disable Source Control GIT in Visual Studio Code Multi Root Workspace

Tags: visual-studio-code

For a multi-root workspace, how could we disable git for one folder while leaving it available for the other folders. Closing the repository only works temporarily, on re-launch, Visual Studio Code picks up on the .git folder again and shows both repositories and the aggregated changes in the Source Control tab.

Comment: where are your `.git` folders

Comment: @rioV8, all roots have their own .git folders. Hence the issue. I was wondering if there was a setting to hide source control of some folders and not others when using multi-root workspaces.

Comment: you want source control of a workspace but you don't want to see the modified status

Comment: @rioV8 only for some of the root folders...